# Chrome Extension Unchecked runtime.lastError while running events.addRules: Host values need to be in lower case

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Receiving error below:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running events.addRules: Host values need to be in lower case.
```

Manifest.json file includes:

```
  {
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["*://*/*","activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
        "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
        "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
            "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      }
    },
        "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

Pretty new to chrome extnesions. I try adding "*://*/*" in permissions following a previous example but not having any luck.

Comment: You didn't show the code that invokes addRules or declarativeContent. I guess it has an incorrect host value.

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.abc.com' },
            })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
```

Do not put any path or query beyond .com, .org, etc.
This helped me resolve this query.